# Disable automatic mercurial rollback execution

Tags: mercurial

I have an issue when trying to clone the repository to local machine via LAN.

At some point an error occurs and all downloaded data are erased during rollback.

Is it possible to turn off the mercurial's automatic rollback on error even though the downloaded data may be corrupted?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't stop it from rolling back -- it won't leave it in an inconsistent state, however you can do the clone incrementally.

Rather than:

```
hg clone http://path/to/your/repo
```

do:

```
hg clone -r 100 http://path/to/your/repo
hg pull -r 200 http://path/to/your/repo
hg pull -r 200 http://path/to/your/repo
... and so on until done ...
```

That gets 100 changesets at a time.  If you have a network failure you'll only have to re-un the last command and eventually you'll get through.

As a note, once you've cloned this to a machine, even once, you **never** have to do it again.  Instead clone from your local repo if you want another clone.

```
hg clone myclone my-other-clone
```

Comment: Thanks! That's probably the best option!